# Which curve has the smoothest curvature : Clothoid or Hypocycloid? Benefits of Hypocycloid in general for making smooth path between two points.

Tags: geometry, curves, curvature

I am investigating hypocycloids for making smooth paths. I would be thankful if you could share some insights on the following two questions:

**Ques 1)** 
Whose curvature is smoother: Clothoid or Hypocycloid (say we limit the discussion only to astroid and deltoid, or in general if possible).

**Ques 2)** 
What could be the potential advantages of using Hypocycloid over Clothoid for making smooth paths?

**Smoothness [source: wiki]**: Smoothness of a function is a property measured by the number of derivatives it has which are continuous. A smooth function is a function that has derivatives of all orders everywhere in its domain. *In terms of robot, I am particularly interested in 1st derivative (velocity), and 2nd derivate (acceleration) only. In this regard, a straight line is not smooth as robot has to very abruptly turn at points A and B. I am interested in which curve has more curvature, which curve keeps more clearance from the obstacle P in the [edited] figure attached.*

Regarding 1) I found the parametric equations for curvatures of hypocyloid and clothoid from [Hypocloid curvature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypocycloid.html) and for clothoid too. But I am unable to interpret the general case. Regarding 2) I found that parametric equations of hypocycloid are easier to compute than clothoids which involves 
Fresnel Integrals.

**Concretely,** 
I am trying to fix a hypocycloid or a clothoid between two points A and B in the figure attached. OA = OB. I would like to know mathematically about whether a hypocycloid (say astroid) or a clothoid curve would be smoother?

**Curvature Equations**
Curvature of a general hypocycloid is given by [from Wolfram Hypocycloid] where $a$ and $b$ are the radius of larger circle and rolling smaller circle:
$c(\phi) = \dfrac{2b - a}{4b(a-b)} cosec \biggl( \dfrac{a\phi}{2b} \biggr)$

For a specific astroid case, curvature is:
$c(\phi) = \dfrac{-2}{3} cosec (2t)$

Curvature of a clothoid = $-t$ (equal to the parameter)

Hence, I cannot generalize which is greater.
For astroid, at $t=0$, the curvature is $\infty$ (which is equal to that of a straight line). Then it gradually decreases. Hence the robot should experience no (or less) jerk. For clothoid, since its curvature is equal to the parameter $t$, it would degenerate quikcly. In these terms, I want to compare hypocycloid and clothoid. Any suggestions?

[Fitting Hypocycloid(astroid) or clothoid between two points for robot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obQyG.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, in addition to the curve between A and B being smooth, you want the curve to **join** smoothly with the lines at A and B. That makes a big difference.

Comment: Yes, that is also a requirement. I have updated the question with curvature equations. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that what you want is the clothoid (Cornu or Euler spiral). This was originally developed to provide a curve with constant acceleration, i.e., no jerk, for railroad track turns. It is still used today for that as well as highway design. See the Wikipedia page "Euler spiral:" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Thanks. I have already solved the problem. You are right. Euler spiral is useful in my case. If you submit your comment as a proper answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Euler spiral (also known as the Cornu spiral or clothoid) is the natural choice for a smooth transition curve, where by smooth we mean one that will not cause an abrupt change in acceleration (i.e., a  *jerk*).

The Euler spiral is usually expressed in terms of the Fresnel integral, which can be expressed in closed form as follows,

$$z(s)=\int_0^s e^{i \pi s^2/2} ds=\frac{1+i}{2} erf\left(\frac{1-i}{2} \sqrt{\pi} \cdot s\right)$$

where $s$ is the arc length. Now it's also known that a spiral can be expressed in terms of it curvature, $\kappa$, namely,

$$z=\int e^{i\int \kappa(s)ds}ds$$

It follows that the natural equation of this spiral  is $\kappa \propto s$, or in term of the radius of curvature, $\rho$

$$\rho s=\text{constant}$$

It is this property that we are interested in. When traversing a bend we seek to assure that the centrifugal force changes continuously in order to avoid a jerk. If this easement is not applied there would be an abrupt change in the acceleration at the point of transition from a straight path to a curved one.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define what you mean by "smooth".

If you just want to join $A$ and $B$, you could use either a straight line or a quarter circle. Both of these are extremely smooth by any reasonable definition.

The quarter circle **is** a clothoid, though a very simple one.

Suppose you want the curve to join smoothly with the straight lines at $A$ and $B$, and be suitable for a robot path. One very simple solution is the cubic Bezier curve whose 4 control points (in order) are $A$, $O$, $O$, $B$. This curve matches the two lines in both tangent direction and curvature, so there should be no sudden "jerk" force as the robot passes through the points $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks Bubba. Sorry for not being specific and unable to ask question in mathematical jargon. I have edited the question and the figure. I am discussing in terms of robot traversing a path. In case of straight line, it has to abruptly turn at pts A and B. But not so in case of curve fitted between A and B. Also curve should avoid collision of robot from obstacle P in figure. Any idea in these terms is welcome. Please tell me if you need more specifications. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Bubba. The robot should experience no jerk and Bezier curves can achieve it. But I am studying hypocycloids to achieve this task. I have edited the question, please have a look. From the curvature equations it seems that initially the curvature of astroid is infinite i.e. same as straight line, then gradually decreases, so robot should not experience a jerk or there should be less jerk (within bounds). I am wondering what benefits hypocycloid has over clothoid in this case. Any suggestion is highly welcome. Thank you in advance.