# How can I find $\Delta_1$ for the first of two reversing curves?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves, arc-length

This is a problem from the design of roadways.  I know someone has the answer, but I haven't been able to work it out myself.  The sketch below shows a single curve made up of two asymmetrical reversing circular arcs.  The arcs are tangent to each-other at the point they meet and there is no tangent segment between them.  Moving from left to right, the curve begins at an angle of zero and ends in a direction that is not equal to zero.

If the radius of the first curve ($R_1$), the orthogonal distance between the start of the first arc and the end of the second arc ($y_T$), and the angle from zero at which the second arc ends ($\theta_1$) are known, what is the subtended angle ($\Delta_1$) of the first arc that will result in two arcs of equal length?

[image]

Since, $L_i=R_i\Delta_i$ and $L_{1}=L_2$, it is fairly simple to see that $R_2=R_1\frac{\Delta_1}{\Delta_2}$ and that $\Delta_1=R_2\frac{\Delta_2}{\Delta_1}$.  But, I cannot use this relationship unless I have some other independent means of determining $R_2$ or $\Delta_1$.  The only variable that is not dependent upon $\Delta_1$ or $R_2$ is the given distance between the start and end of the curve (measured in a direction orthogonal to the start direction of the first arc).

I can easily use the Solver function in Excel to determine the unique angle that will make everything work, but I am trying to write an algorithm that will draw the reversing curve in cad.  That means I can't use Excel's solver function and I need to figure out how to arrange the equations to find $\Delta_1$ without using $R_2$ or $\Delta_2$.

Assume that any of the typical formulas for circular arcs are available, such as the tangent length, the chord length, mid-ordinate length, etc.  I also know calculus and linear algebra so feel free to use whatever mathematics you think best answers the question.  Thank you.

Comment: A second equation involving $y_T$ can be found, but the resolvent equation for $\Delta_1$ has to be solved numerically.

Comment: Exactly why must it be solved numerically?  I accept the truth of your answer, but I am struggling with why a unique solution cannot be found analytically.  Isn't this a curve that can be integrated?  Thanks for the answer, and it explains why I have been spinning my wheels with this one for a while.   I guess now the task becomes writing an algorithm that will zero in on the correct solution numerically.  At this point, that seems less difficult than what I have been trying to do.  :)

Comment: Being blind, I cannot see the figure. Could you write equations ?

Comment: Are you aware the curved roadways are designed with Cornu spirals, not circular  arcs? See a previous answer of mine here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681278/which-curve-has-the-smoothest-curvature-clothoid-or-hypocycloid-benefits-of-h/2226404#2226404

Comment: In California, Caltrans typically uses circular curves.  Occasionally spirals for mountain roads or special situations.

Comment: Can the  total curve length $x_T$ be assumed /given?

Answer (score 1):

There is another easy relation to exploit:
$$
\theta=\Delta_1-\Delta_2,
$$
where $\theta$ has to be taken as negative if it goes "downwards" in the figure.

Another equality can be found for $y_T$:
$$
y_T=R_1(1-\cos\Delta_1)+2R_2
\sin{\Delta_2\over2}
\sin{2\Delta_1-\Delta_2\over2}.
$$
Inserting here $\Delta_2=\Delta_1-\theta$
and using some trig identities
one gets:
$$
y_T=R_1(1-\cos\Delta_1)+R_2(\cos\theta-\cos\Delta_1).
$$
Use now $R_2=R_1(\Delta_1/\Delta_2)=R_1\Delta_1/(\Delta_1-\theta)$
to get the final equation for $\Delta_1$. Unfortunately, that equation cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions.